# How would you store multiple sets of data with the same name but different entrys firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Hi i have a form the user fills out within my app which includes the following:
title, username, password, webAddress and note.
My current code stores the data for one entry no problem but when i go to enter a new entry the data gets overwritten. I need to be able to store multiple entrys of the form. What would i need to change on my code to enable this?

The strings are encrypted via other code in my program thats why its surrounded by a try/catch.

```
 public void storePassword() {
        final String title_entry = title.getText().toString().trim();
        final String username_entry = title.getText().toString().trim();
        final String password_entry = title.getText().toString().trim();
        final String webaddress_entry = title.getText().toString().trim();
        final String note_entry = title.getText().toString().trim();



        Map<String, Object> user = new HashMap<>();
        try {
            user.put("title", EncryptDecrypt.encryptString(title_entry, Password));
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeySpecException | InvalidKeyException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException | NoSuchPaddingException | IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            user.put("username", EncryptDecrypt.encryptString(username_entry, Password));
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeySpecException | InvalidKeyException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException | NoSuchPaddingException | IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            user.put("password", EncryptDecrypt.encryptString(password_entry, Password));
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeySpecException | InvalidKeyException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException | NoSuchPaddingException | IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            user.put("webAddress", EncryptDecrypt.encryptString(webaddress_entry, Password));
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeySpecException | InvalidKeyException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException | NoSuchPaddingException | IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            user.put("note", EncryptDecrypt.encryptString(note_entry, Password));
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeySpecException | InvalidKeyException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException | NoSuchPaddingException | IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        userID = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        fDatasebase.collection("Users").document(userID).update(user);

    }
```

Comment: If you are always using the same `userID`, that's the normal behavior.

Comment: @AlexMamo How could i modify this? because the entrys entered need to be linked to that specific user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want store multiple forms per user, you can't use the same document ID for each form.  You should instead use a random document ID, and store the user ID as a field in the document.

```
Map<String, Object> user = new HashMap<>();
// populate the map as you were

// put the UID in the map
String uid = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
user.put("uid", uid);

// Add the document to the colleciton with a random ID
fDatasebase.collection("Users").add(user);
```

To get all the forms for the user, you can just query "Users" with a filter on the `uid` field.

Comment: Thank you for your help, i have tried implementing your method but its returning an error when trying to ".add(user)" error message > cannot resolve method 'add(java.util.Map<java.lang.String.java.lang.object>)

Comment: It was a typo. Fixed now.